# How to get the Browser(IE) Print page setup using javascript/Classic asp

Tags: javascript, asp-classic

Using JavaScript/classic asp how to get the Browser(IE) print page setup details?

For Ex:Page size,Header,Footer,Margins,Enable shrink-to-Fit.

Answer (score 1):

Add 2 types of css , first for html render, second for printing

- HTML:  `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/stylesheets.css" media="screen"/>`
- PRINT : `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/printstyle.css" media="print"/>`

Make JQUERY Action on button click :

```
$(document).on( 'click', '#print', function () {
var ifr = document.createElement('iframe');
var html = $("html").html(); //<<HERE GOES ID OF TAG WHICH PART OF DOCUMENT YOU WANT TO PRINT . IN THIS EXAMPLE IT WILL PRINT ENTIRE DOCUMENT...
ifr.src = 'about:blank';
ifr.setAttribute('style', 'display: none;');
ifr.onload = function (event) {
ifr.contentDocument.body.innerHTML = html;
ifr.contentWindow.print();
};
document.body.appendChild(ifr);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your Answers,but i want to JavaScript not a J Query.
Pl. advise to implement using JavaScript.

Comment: this is plain javascript except onclick event , just make javasript function and call on your tag `onclicl="yourmethod()"` and replace `var html = document.documentElement.innerHTML;` thats all

Comment: Sir,Actually i want to getting the Browser print page setup using JavaScript.If suppose the left margin is "0.05" in a browser it means,i need to shown the alert for JavaScript "Your Print page setup Left margin is:0.05"
I hope you understood what am trying to say.PL. advise...

Answer (score 0):

it is not possible to set the print page Setup with JavaScript. this is a functionality of the browser (in your case IE) nothing to do with JavaScript/dom/html

Comment: Is it Possible for Classic asp??

Comment: @Sabarirajan well, no because classic asp is executed on the Server and the browser runs on the Client. you could create a pdf with classic asp...

Comment: @ ulluoink: If any other way to possible for pragmatically??
Like jquery,Vbscript..

Comment: @Sabarirajan jquery is JavaScript. vbscript only works in IE and you will have to set lots of security things in the clientside IE to make vbscript work. furthermore i am not sure IF it works with vbscript